# openssl strange verify status

Tags: apache, openssl, certificate

I use openssl to verify whether my installation of VeriSign certificate is ok. I install it on
several servers(A, B, C), only on server B, I run command "openssl s_client -connect A:443" I can get " Verify return code: 0 (ok)". well, on A or C, when I verify, get "Verify return code: 21", what's the problem?

Comment: This looks more like missing Intermediate Certificate on the failing servers. Can you confirm if you have installed the VeriSign intermediate certificate chain

Comment: Yes, I am sure. because when I run "openssl s_client -connect A:443" on A itself, which is ok. well, when I run the same command on server B, which return "Verify return code: 21"

Comment: But your initial comment was that it worked only on B but not A&C. So confirm again which server this isn't working on

Comment: sorry for make you misunderstood. here A,B,C isn't important, just a description of there relationship,  on A: openssl s_client A:443 it is ok, on B: openssl s_client A:443 failed...

Comment: yesterday, I use 'strace' to trace the verify process, and I found it use /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.pem, how can I regenerate the ca-bundle.pem by 'intermediate.pem', 'server.key', 'server.crt'?